# railties (LoadError) Cannot load such file

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

I've got a Ruby on Rails app, just added `rspec-rails` and I tried to run:

`rails generate rspec:install`

But received this:

`` /usr/local/bin/rails:23:in `load': cannot load such file -- /usr/share
/rubygems-integration/all/gems/railties-4.2.6/bin/rails (LoadError) ``

From my Gemfile...

`gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.5'`

And I'm running Rails v4.2.5.1

Comment: maybe `bundle exec rails`? Seems like an issue loading Rails itself how did you install it? `gem install rails` or `sudo gem instal rails`?Do you have `rbenv` or `rvm`?

Comment: I've just done `sudo gem install rails` and now my command from earlier works!

Answer (score 0):

I've just done `sudo gem install rails` and now it works.