# 'require': cannot load such file 'gem' (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I realize there is a ton of questions identical to this however I have had no success in fixing my issue. I am trying to use the gem 'vpn' and for learning purposes I figured I would open up a brand new project. Having followed the installation instructions on: https://github.com/ronen/vpn (the gem is also on rubygems.org) and requiring the gem in my code, I get `require': cannot load such file -- vpn (LoadError)`.

I have verified my version. `gem env` gives

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.7.7
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.5.1 (2018-03-29 patchlevel 57) [x86_64-darwin17]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/user/.gem/ruby/2.5.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/user/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-17
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1
     - /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin
     - /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@global/bin
     - /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin
     - /Users/user/.rvm/bin
     - /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin
     - /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS
```

`ruby --version` gives `ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-darwin17]`

In my gem file I have `gem: 'vpn'`

`gem list` does return `vpn (0.2.1)`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

What I have tried:

- Reinstalling the gem
- Manually moving the gem to the location
- Sudo gem install
- [Many: `require': cannot load such file -- "gem_name" (LoadError) after upgrade of ruby/rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26360657/many-require-cannot-load-such-file-gem-name-loaderror-after-upgrade-o)
- [Rails: LoadError - Cannot load such file (requiring a gem)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25160377/rails-loaderror-cannot-load-such-file-requiring-a-gem) (I do not have a server going)
- [gem which cannot find gem despite it being installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261981/gem-which-cannot-find-gem-despite-it-being-installed)
- [railties (LoadError) Cannot load such file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42379882/railties-loaderror-cannot-load-such-file)
- [How to check if a gem is installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22211711/how-to-check-if-a-gem-is-installed)

P.S I do not have a rake file. I haven't set one up because I'm not too entirely sure it will fix my problem and I've had problems finding out how to create one.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here seems to be with the way the `vpn` gem is structured.
Modern gems have a pattern:

- executables are placed inside the `bin` / `exe` directories in the gem
- Ruby code is placed in a `<gem-name>.rb`file inside a `lib` directory in the gem

So, when a user calls `require <gem-name>`, Ruby tries to load `<gem-name>-<gem-version>/lib/<gem-name>.rb` and returns a `LoadError` if it doesn't.
For example, when a user has listed `gem 'jekyll', '3.8.0'` in their `Gemfile`,
Ruby will try to load `jekyll-3.8.0/lib/jekyll.rb` first by default.

For Ruby to load another directory instead of `~/lib/`, the `<gem-name>.gemspec` should specify that via the `require_paths=` setting.
For example, to load `david.rb` file (from hypothetical gem named `david-rb` at version `0.1.0`) installed at `~/gems/david-rb-0.1.0/code/david.rb`, the `david-rb.gemspec` should have the following:

```
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  # preceding lines ...

  s.require_paths = ["lib", "code"]

  # following lines ...
end
```

Now when a consumer of `david-rb` gem calls `require 'david'`, Ruby will first try to load `david.rb` from `~/gems/david-rb-0.1.0/lib/` and then from `~/gems/david-rb-0.1.0/code/` without raising an error.